# Upgrade to Laravel 5.3 - Mail::send now returns null from Mandrill

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, mandrill

I'm upgrading from Laravel 5.2 to 5.3 but since doing so the Mail::send function no returns null when sending via Mandrill.

I had the same issue in Laravel 4.2, but it seems this functionality was then added when upgrading to version 5.

```
$response = Mail::send($template, $email, function($message) use($subject)
{
    $message->to('test@example.com')->subject($subject);
});

dd($response)
```

Message sends fine, but the response is null where is gave the message ID/content in 5.1 & 5.2 before the upgrade

I can't understand why they would add the feature then remove it again?

Answer (score 0):

This is because the syntax has fundamentally changed. You need to use the [Mailable Class](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/mail#generating-mailables) rather than a callback.

Your code should look something like this:

```
Mail::to('test@example.com')->send(new EmailExample($data));
```

Where `EmailExample` is a class that extends `Mailable` and handles your email body and any applicable logic.

See the [docs here for further information](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/mail)

Comment: Nope it does the same. I watched a Laracasts video on the new Mailable functionality in 5.3 and Jeffery explains it as just a wrapper around Mail::send. In any case I just tried and even using Mailable it still returns null